# How to run a .net 4.5 app on local that has a website.publishproj file

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.5

I am trying to run an old .net app.  I'm used to seeing .sln files but this project has a website.publishproj file.

I am able to build the project by right clicking the website.publishproj file and selecting "Build" but I just get that it was successful, I need this to run in a browser:

[image]

I'm *taking a guess* that the .publishproj file is the relevant one, so I'm including the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--

***********************************************************************************************
website.publishproj

WARNING: DO NOT MODIFY this file, it is used for the web publish process.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

***********************************************************************************************
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.30319</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{f4e28bbe-e8b3-4faa-8b4d-c6e36eee6659}</ProjectGuid>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/LaunchPad</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <SourceWebProject>http://localhost:56565</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebMetabasePath>/IISExpress/7.5/LM/W3SVC/16/ROOT</SourceWebMetabasePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- for VS2010 we need to use 10.5 but for VS2012+ we should use VisualStudioVersion -->
    <WebPublishTargetsVersion Condition=" '$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)' =='' and '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == 10.0 ">10.5</WebPublishTargetsVersion>
    <WebPublishTargetsVersion Condition=" '$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)'=='' ">$(VisualStudioVersion)</WebPublishTargetsVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(WebPublishTargetsVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <_WebPublishTargetsPath Condition=" '$(_WebPublishTargetsPath)'=='' ">$(VSToolsPath)</_WebPublishTargetsPath>
    <AssemblyFileVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyFileVersion)' == ''">1.0.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyVersion)' == ''">1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyFileVersion">
      <Value>$(AssemblyFileVersion)</Value>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyVersion">
      <Value>$(AssemblyVersion)</Value>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(_WebPublishTargetsPath)\Web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets" />
</Project>
```

How do I run this so it website actually runs in a browser?

Comment: Neither this nor`.sln` are project files. `.sln` files are solution files that point to the actual project files. They don't even include project references. `publishproj`, as the comments say, it's a publish project. You don't run it, you use it to publish projects.

Comment: This may be a [web site project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110)) a type that was deprecated by the time .NET Framework 4.5 came out and eventually discontinued. The source was deployed as is, not precompiled. ASP.NET on the server would compile each file separately. While this made ad-hoc development easier (you could just upload a modified source file) it was a big problem for .. just about anything we do nowadays: testing, staging, versioning. Never mind security.

Comment: You're correct; my co-worker showed me how to open a "website" in Visual Studio, which is what I needed to do in order to run this on my local